# Payment for or payment of

Tags: prepositions

> This house was rented with an advance payment of six months’ rent.

> This house was rented with an advance payment for six months’ rent.

In this sentence should I use ''of'' or ''for''?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - (1) This house was rented with an advance payment of six months’ rent.

> - (2) This house was rented with an advance payment for six months’ rent.

The usage in sentence  (1) is in my experience significantly more common than the usage in sentence (2). HGowever, a fluent speaker would understand and might use either.

In general "Payment of X" is used when X represents a sum of money, while "payment for Y" is used when Y is a purpose, or a good or service to be purchased or paid for. "one month's rent" can be thought of as an amount (often specified in a lease or agreement) or as the purpose of the payment, so either form is reasonable in this particular case. Cases where only one form would be natural include:

> - I made the payment **for** my new watch by credit card. [Use of ***of*** would suggest a payment in wtches, which is not usual.]

> - The impound lot demanded a payment **of** $500 before they would release my car. [The use of ***for*** would suggest one is buying the money, which is simply incorrect.]